# javascript : can I generate CRUD grid and form from rest service

Tags: javascript, rest, generator

Can I generate grid and forms from rest API

I want do it in an easiest reusable way.

EXTJS, JQUERY, MOOTOOLS, PROTOTYPE is not welcome

Comment: Do you want to do it yourself, or which framework would you be willing to use?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here's an example from ExtJs:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/restful/restful.html

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dvv/schema2form -- JSON-schema to form generator
--dvv

Comment: can you add an demo for schema2form